# Variable substitution not taking effect within ARM template files

Tags: octopus-deploy, azure-rm-template

I have an OD project where one step of the process is the `Deploy an Azure Resource Group` step. The templates are contained within a package.

According to the [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/azure-deployments/resource-groups#DeployusinganAzureResourceGroupTemplate-TemplateContainedinaPackage):

> Octopus will perform variable-substitution on both the Template and Parameter files.

And according to the [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploying-asp.net-core-web-applications/json-configuration-variables-feature#JSONConfigurationVariablesFeature-Hierarchicalvariables) for JSON variable substitution, the correct variable format should be `parameters:sqlServerAdminUsername:value` given a template file like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sqlServerAdminUsername": {
      "value": "thisvalueshouldbereplaced"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the ARM template is using the original values from the parameters file, as opposed to the values that I have supplied in my OD variables.

What am I doing wrong?